# Pandas aggregate grouping & summing

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe where I am trying to sum based on groupings, but I can't seem to get the order right. In the example below, I want to groupby group2 then group1 and sum without double-counting the group1 values. This is part of a larger table with other things going on, so I don't want to filter-out by unique group1-2 sets.

Using pandas 1.0.5

```
x, y = [(21643,21665,21640,21668,21713,21706), (30,28,84,2,32,-9)]
val = [11,27,31,15,50,35]
group1, group2 = [(1,1,3,4,1,4), (21660,21660,21660,21660,21700,21700)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, val, group1, group2)), 
                  columns =['x', 'y', 'val', 'group1', 'group2']
                 ) 

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.sort_values(['group2', 'group1'],inplace=True)
df['group1_mean'] = df.groupby(['group2', 'group1'])['val'].transform('mean')
df['group2_sum'] = df.groupby(['group2', 'group1'])['group1_mean'].transform('sum')
display(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a temporary df

```
dfsum = df.groupby(['group2', 'group1']).mean()
dfsum = dfsum.groupby('group2').sum()
```

Then merge df with this dfsum

```
df = df.merge(dfsum, on='group2')
```

---

### The one line trick

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['group2', 'group1']).val.mean()
    .groupby('group2').sum().rename('result'), on='group2')
```

This will not assign a new variable name so groupby intermediate dfs will be garbage-collected.

Output

```
       x   y  val  group1  group2  result
0  21643  30   11       1   21660      65
1  21665  28   27       1   21660      65
2  21640  84   31       3   21660      65
3  21668   2   15       4   21660      65
4  21713  32   50       1   21700      85
5  21706  -9   35       4   21700      85
```

Comment: it seems like there should be a cleaner way to do it by rolling it into .apply() or an anonymous function?

Comment: `df = df.merge(df.groupby(['group2', 'group1']).mean().groupby('group2').sum().rename('this_is_my_result'), on='group2')` throw error `TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'this_is_my_result' was passed`

Comment: my mistake, I failed to include a `.val` after the first groupby... try it now